# Prevent the first renderPlot in the nested module

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I create plot pipeline using nested modules.
It works ok, but two things are annoying.

1. `rendPlot` works before I even click `input$update`, and while the app doesn't crash, there is an ERROR in the console.
2. And another thing is that the `downloadButton` can't be disabled!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)

point_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    # upload and many ggplot paremeters
    actionButton(ns("data_import"), label = "Data import"),
    sliderInput(ns("point_size"), label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 4, value = 2),
  )
}

point_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    dat <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    name <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    # mimic uploading a file
    observeEvent(input$data_import, {
      dat(iris)
      name("iris")
    })

    # ... here should be some updateSelectInput after upload

    plot_1 <- reactive({
      p <- ggplot(data = dat(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(size = input$point_size)
      return(p)
    })

    plot_final <- gglabels_server(NULL, plot_1)

    output_show_server(NULL, plot_final, name, id)

  })
}

output_show_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("update"), "update"),
    sliderInput(ns("height"), "height", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
    sliderInput(ns("width"), "width", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
    downloadButton(ns("png"), "png"),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"), width = 250, height = 250)
  )
}

output_show_server <- function(id, plot_final, prefix, suffix) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    # disable the downloadButton
    observe({
      toggleState("png", condition = !is.null(prefix()))
    })

    output$png <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0(prefix(), "_", suffix, ".png")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        ggsave(file, plot = plot_final(), device = "png", width = input$width, height = input$height, unit = "px", dpi = 72)
      }
    )

    # dynamic size, the plot should only show and refresh after click 
    output$plot <- renderPlot(
      width = function() input$width,
      height = function() input$height,
      {
        input$update
        isolate({
          plot_final()
        })
      }
    )
  })
}

gglabels_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("title"), label = "content of title", value = "main title"),
    textInput(ns("subtitle"), label = "content of subtitle", value = "sub title")
  )
}

gglabels_server <- function(id, ggobj) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    p_return <- reactive({
      p <- ggobj() + labs(
        title = input$title,
        subtitle = input$subtitle
      )
      return(p)
    })
    return(p_return)
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("nested modules"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        point_ui("test"),
        gglabels_ui("test"),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        output_show_ui("test")
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    point_server("test")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error you can use `req()`, and to disable the download button, you can use `disable()` from shinyjs.  Try this

```
output_show_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton(ns("update"), "update"),
    sliderInput(ns("height"), "height", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
    sliderInput(ns("width"), "width", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
    downloadButton(ns("png"), "png"),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"), width = 250, height = 250)
  )
}

output_show_server <- function(id, plot_final, prefix, suffix) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # disable the downloadButton
    observe({
      #shinyjs::toggleState("png", condition = !is.null(prefix()))
      if (is.null(prefix())) {
        shinyjs::disable("png")
      }else shinyjs::enable("png")
    })
    
    output$png <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0(prefix(), "_", suffix, ".png")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        ggsave(file, plot = plot_final(), device = "png", width = input$width, height = input$height, unit = "px", dpi = 72)
      }
    )
    
    # dynamic size, the plot should only show and refresh after click 
    output$plot <- renderPlot(
      width = function() input$width,
      height = function() input$height,
      {
        req(input$update,plot_final())
        isolate({
          plot_final()
        })
      }
    )
  })
}
```